# How to send a 410 gone in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, http-response-codes

I want to the server a 410 gone response for my old unpublished URLs in CakePHP.

CakePHP provides a variety of exceptions like 404, 500 etc. but there is nothing like 410 gone.

**Is there any way I can server 410 gone response if someone opens an old URL that no longer exists on the website but used to be.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did followings to resolved this.

I added "gone" function in "AppExceptionRenderer"

```
public function gone($error) {

        $this->controller->layout = 'nopageexists';

        $this->controller->set('title_for_layout', __('example.com: Page not found'));
        $this->controller->set('meta_description', '' );
        $this->controller->set('meta_keywords', '');

        // This will execute 404 Error Page without redirection added by vinod...
        $this->controller->response->statusCode(410);
        $this->controller->render('/Errors/error404');
        $this->controller->response->send();
    }
```

Created a custom class in app/Lib/myException.php

```
class GoneException extends CakeException {

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param string $message If no message is given 'Not Found' will be the message
 * @param integer $code Status code, defaults to 410
  */
    /*
    public function __construct($message = null, $code = 410) {
        if (empty($message)) {
            $message = 'Gone';
        }
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }
    */
    protected $_messageTemplate = 'Test';
}
```

Added below in Controller where I want to show 410 gone.

```
throw new GoneException('Gone', 410);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way is throwing exceptions. The exceptions extending the HttpException. You can also extends from this class and create your own custom exception.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Network/Exception/BadRequestException.php

```
<?php

use Cake\Network\Exception\HttpException;

class GoneException extends HttpException
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $message If no message is given 'Gone' will be the message
     * @param int $code Status code, defaults to 410
     */
    public function __construct($message = null, $code = 410)
    {
        if (empty($message)) {
            $message = 'Gone';
        }
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }
}
```

Comment: for your helps. I override the "AppExceptionRenderer" that resolved this issue. Please see details in my answer.